# Not Conforming To The UITableViewDataSource

Tags: swift

```
class EmployeeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var employees = [PFEmployee]()

var networking = Networking()

var plus: UIBarButtonItem!
var profile: UIBarButtonItem!

var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return employees.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CustomTableViewCell {
    let cell: CustomTableViewCell! = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "customCell")

    cell.nameLabel.text = employees[indexPath.row].name
    cell.pointsLabel.text = employees[indexPath.row].numberOfPoints.toString()
    cell.roleLabel.text = employees[indexPath.row].jobDesc
    cell.commentaryLabel.text = employees[indexPath.row].commentary

    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

For some reason, I get two errors :

1. `Cannot assign a value of type 'EmployeeViewController' to a value of type 'UITableViewDataSource?'`
2. `Type 'EmployeeViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource.'`

**I have clearly implemented all of the methods that are required, so what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declaration is wrong. Change this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CustomTableViewCell {
```

to this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

(Your method must return a `UITableViewCell`, not a `CustomTableViewCell`.) This implicit casting would be OK in Objective-C but isn't allowed in Swift, where casting must be explicit.

---

A few unrelated things:

- `var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()` can simply be `let tableView = UITableView()`
- You have a lot of unnecessary `self.` that you can remove.

Comment: @RehaanAdvani Great! If your issue is resolved, please click the check box to the left of my answer. This will signal to other users that you don't need additional help.